# Sort two array of hashes by the same criteria on Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, sorting, hash

I am working on Ruby with two arrays of hashes like these:

```
a = [{'name'=> 'Ana', 'age'=> 42 },
     {'name'=> 'Oscar', 'age'=> 22 },
     {'name'=> 'Dany', 'age'=> 12 }]

b = [{'name'=> 'Dany', 'country'=> 'Canada' },
     {'name'=> 'Oscar', 'country'=> 'Peru'},
     {'name'=> 'Ana', 'country'=>'France'}]
```

I am sorting them like this:

```
a.sort_by!{|c| c['name']}
b.sort_by!{|c| c['name']}
```

and it works, but since I doing the same on both arrays, I would like doing the same but in one line; I mean, sort the two arrays at once.

How can I do it?

Comment: It's _two separate arrays_, why do you expect it to be possible to sort them at the same time?

Comment: Because the function and criteria are the same.

Comment: Are you looking to combine and sort them (which the first two answers below do) or to sort them separately and still end up with two arrays?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just put them in an array.

```
a = [{'name'=> 'Ana', 'age'=> 42 },
     {'name'=> 'Oscar', 'age'=> 22 },
     {'name'=> 'Dany', 'age'=> 12 }]

b = [{'name'=> 'Dany', 'country'=> 'Canada' },
     {'name'=> 'Oscar', 'country'=> 'Peru'},
     {'name'=> 'Ana', 'country'=>'France'}]

[a, b].each{|ar| ar.sort_by!{|c| c['name']}}
p b # => [{"name"=>"Ana", "country"=>"France"}, {"name"=>"Dany", "country"=>"Canada"}, {"name"=>"Oscar", "country"=>"Peru"}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Simpler way -

```
  a.zip(b).flatten.sort_by!{|c| c['name']})
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question. The OP wants to sort each array, not combine the arrays in some way, then sort. Also, `zip` is a bit odd here: `require 'set'; a.zip(b).flatten.to_set == a.concat(b).flatten.to_set #=> true`. That is, `a.zip(b).flatten` produces the same array as `a.concat(b).flatten`, just in a different order that does not seem to have any significance. Also, you have a problem with `zip` when the arrays are not the same size.